# Which is better? Use static methods or create new instance each time?

Tags: java, android, performance

I have about 15 methods and I will use it so much in my application. I put all my methods in one class and I will call it each time I need them. I am using java programming language to create mobile application. Which is better?

```
new MethodHolder().myMethod();
```

or

```
MethodHolder.myMethod();
```

Which is better for performance or memory ?

Comment: There's no "better" here. The two are very different.

Comment: don't you know how to use punctuation? -_-

Comment: *"use static methods or create new instatnce each time?"* having non static method does not imply to create a new instance for each call.

Comment: use the concept of singleton class here. Create instance of this class at first run using the application class and then call the methods using that instance. This will help you to optimize memory and will not create a new object of the same class if already exists, this you have to handle.

Comment: Profiling each strategy is the better way to have a factual answer.

Comment: no what mean  punctuation? Baby?

Comment: Ankush Bist Good idea (Y)

Comment: Don't worry about performance on that level. Create clean, easy to maintain code. Handle performance problems when they come up. Then analyze where you need to improve. This will most likely not be where you expect it.

Comment: Yeah, design patterns are used when you have a problem you need solved.  You don't have a problem right now.  Just make those methods static for now.

Comment: Thanks so much for all <3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I write my projects I almost always have my "ProjectUtil" class that contains all the static utility methods that I need all over the project (or package) itself, so I'd suggest to make some classes of static methods, since they need no access to instance variables.

Answer (score 3):

In my personal opinion, I would prefer the latter because the methods are just there to help you to write less repeated code. They are *utility methods*. Utility methods are generally static because they don't really need to maintain any "state". Creating a new instance just to call a utility method is unnecessary.

> Which is better for performance or memory ?

There is no need to worry about performance when there isn't any problems. Premature optimization is the root of evil. Worry about these problems when you *do* have them, and when you have done everything else that's more important than performace.

Comment: `Premature optimization is the root of evil.` This is **highly opinionable**.

Comment: @Rotwang a) It's supposed to be a quote. b) It's pretty widely accepted as sensible advice.

Comment: a) It's a **highly opinionable** quote. b) It's only true if you don't know what you are doing. But, yes, a lot of developers don't know what they are doing. Therefore it is "widely accepted".

Comment: @Rotwang: You can safely consider “*premature optimization*” as evil without stopping thinking about performance in advance. It all boils down to the question when it starts becoming “premature”. Or whether choosing the better of two alternatives is already “optimization”.

Comment: @Holger I can safely consider “premature optimization” as a BEST PRACTICE. So, no way I'll ever consider it "evil".